# Having trouble adding up two floating point values

Tags: floating-point

I've been trying to add up two values into a single precision floating point value but I'm not getting the right answer.

In decimal they are
10^7
and
1.5

What is the 32 bit floating point value of these values added.
Also what is the decimal value if I convert the floating result into decimal?

I'm getting 10,000,001.0(after I add floating point values then convert to decimal) which isn't right

Should be 10,000,001.5

Answer (score 2):

In range 8388608...16777216 (2^23...2^24), step between sequential values represented in 32-bit float is equal to 1. You can't represent 10,000,001.5 exactly; the closest values of this type are 10,000,001 and 10,000,002.

Switch to `double` if you need more precision.